# Fuzzy C means in python for brain tumor detection

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation, fuzzy-c-means

I found this code on GitHub and i try to understand the behavior of functions.I tried to compare this code with the formulas (from p. 6 of [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-2289/3/2/27)):

[image]

I cannot find where this formulas are implemented into the code.Can anyone help me to explain the similarities between the formulas and the code?

```
class FCM() :
    def __init__(self, n_clusters=17, max_iter=100, m=2, error=1e-6):
        super().__init__()
        self.u, self.centers = None, None
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.m = m
        self.error = error

def fit(self, X):
    N = X.shape[0]
    C = self.n_clusters
    centers = []

    u = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(C), size=N)

    iteration = 0
    while iteration < self.max_iter:
        u2 = u.copy()

        centers = self.next_centers(X, u)
        u = self.next_u(X, centers)
        iteration += 1

        # Stopping rule
        if norm(u - u2) < self.error:
            break

    self.u = u
    self.centers = centers
    return centers

def next_centers(self, X, u):
    um = u ** self.m
    return (X.T @ um / np.sum(um, axis=0)).transpose()  #Vi

def next_u(self, X, centers):
    return self._predict(X, centers)

def _predict(self, X, centers):
    power = float(2 / (self.m - 1))
    temp = cdist(X, centers) ** power
    denominator_ = temp.reshape((X.shape[0], 1, -1)).repeat(temp.shape[-1], axis=1)
    denominator_ = temp[:, :, np.newaxis] / denominator_

    return 1 / denominator_.sum(2)

def predict(self, X):
    if len(X.shape) == 1:
        X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)

    u = self._predict(X, self.centers)
    return np.argmax(u, axis=-1)

img2 = ret.reshape(x * y, z)
    algorithm = FCM()
    cluster_centers = algorithm.fit(img2)
    output = algorithm.predict(img2)
    img = cluster_centers[output].astype(np.int16).reshape(x, y, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most relevant parts are the following:

- The function `fit` describes the general steps of the algorithm:

  - a few initializations
  - the updates to the centers and labels (which are delegated to other functions)
  - a verification of the stopping criteria after each iteration (`norm(u - u2) < self.error`).
- The fuzzy membership from equation **(4)** is implemented inside the function `_predict`:

  - The exponent is stored in `power`
  - The norms of differences are taken care of by [`cdist` from scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). A single call to this function is used to compute the distances between all combinations of a data point x<sub>j</sub> and a cluster center v<sub>i</sub>. Each of the results is raised to the `power` and the result is stored in a `temp` array.
  - The last 3 lines of `_predict` juggle around the entries of the `temp` array in such a way that, without loops, it computes the divisions between each "distance" and the appropriate sum of "distances" (actually, "`power` of distance(s)", but it is easier to ignore the exponent at first). For this, the code uses a few tricks available in numpy, such as [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), and [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).
- The fuzzy centers from equation **(5)** are computed by `next_centers`:

  - Precompute a matrix `um` containing the `m`-th power of each u<sub>ij</sub> (for later use in both the numerator and denominator)
  - Use `np.sum(um, axis=0)` to create an array whose `i`-th entry is the sum which is used in the denominator when computing the `i`-th cluster
  - For the `i`-th cluster, the numerator of **(5)** will be computed in the `i`-th column of `X.T @ um` (which becomes a row once we `.transpose()`the resulting matrix)